# Correct way to include image via relative path

Tags: sass, laravel-mix, node-sass, resolve-url-loader

I've updated **laravel-mix** to version `4.0.12` and faced with broken build on the line in `*.scss` where I used a relative path to include background image

I got a next files structure

```
resources/
|-assets/
||-img/
|||-background.png
||-sass/
|||-footer.scss
```

my code in **footer.scss** is next

```
.footer {
  background-image: url(../img/background.png)
}
```

My **webpack.mix.js** is next

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const resourcesAssets = 'resources/assets/';
const dest = 'public/assets/';

mix
  .copy(`${resourcesAssets}images`, `${dest}images`, false)
  .sass(`${resourcesAssets}scss/footer.scss`, `${dest}css`);
```

During compling `npm run prod` I got

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
predicate must return an absolute path or the result of calling next()
at file://C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\resources\assets\sass\footer.scss:2:3
at encodeError (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:218:12)
at onFailure (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:175:14)
at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at runLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at onFailure (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:175:5)
    at <anonymous>
        at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:5)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

        error  in ./resources/assets/sass/footer.scss
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an URL rewriting thing in Webpack as Laravel Mix is built on top of Webpack. For CSS compilation, Webpack rewrites and optimizes any `url()` calls within your stylesheets.

However, according to the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#url-processing):

> Absolute paths for any given `url()` will be excluded from URL-rewriting. For example, `url('/images/thing.png')` or `url('http://example.com/images/thing.png')` won't be modified.

So, Mix tries to rewrite your CSS to sth. like:

```
.footer {
    background-image: url(/img/background.png?<some-hash-identifier>)
}
```

In that case, you can disable `url()` like so and Mix will not touch `url(../img/background.png)` in your **footer.scss**:

```
mix.sass(`${resourcesAssets}scss/footer.scss`, `${dest}css`);
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of underhood `url()` processing. Origin problem can be resolved via my answer, while this is another way to handle `url()`.

Comment: Your welcome! This should also overcome the fallback to older versions of `resolve-url-loader`.

Comment: Thanks mate for this answer with great explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was in too new `"resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0"`.

After installing an intermediate version `"laravel-mix": "~3"` some time ago it was added to **package.json**.

Removing it and rerun build helps me to resolve the problem. laravel-mix added `"resolve-url-loader": "2.3.1"` after running `npm run prod`.

Comment: Thank you @pavlo-zhukov, removing `resolve-url-loader` from my **package.json** and letting `laravel-mix` include the version it needs via its dependencies resolved my issue.

I am using `laravel-mix: 4.x` and this installed `resolve-url-loader: 2.3.1

Clearly `laravel-mix` isn't compatible with `resolve-url-loader: 3.0` at this time.

Comment: @SlyDave I'm glad to hear that my answer helps someone else. It is the main reason why I put it here :)